# JSON empty when is called from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb

I'm learning NodeJS and MongoDB. I dont know what is happening with this function.

```
getAllUsers = async () = {

let user;
let result = await new Connection().connect();
if (result.status == "ok")
    {
        user = await User.find();

    }
return user;
};
```

If I make a console.log before return user, it works fine (just print an JSON array with all info of the collection)

The problem is when I call it from another file (in my case, the router). If I do this, I receive an empty json.

Why is this happening?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling your function getAllUsers, you need to add await in front of it since it is an async function.

For example,

```
var listUsers = await getAllUsers();
```

Comment: so i would need to make the router.get function async, isn't it?

Comment: @Angel yes, you could use something like router.get(path, asyncWrapper(async (req) => { [your code] return await getAllUsers() }));